# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'legendHandles' while manually assigning color to each label in custom legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running three different `for` loops for analyzing three different datasets. However, data from all is plotted into one. Also, I am trying to assign a color to the customized legend. Here is my code:

```
    for j in green_data:
        x,y = blah.....
        plt.plot(x,y,'g')
    for j in black_data:
        x,y = blah.....
        plt.plot(x,y,'k')
    for j in red_data:
        x,y = blah.....
        plt.plot(x,y,'r')
    ax = plt.gca()
    leg = ax.get_legend()
    leg.legendHandles[0].set_color('green')
    leg.legendHandles[1].set_color('black')
    leg.legendHandles[2].set_color('red')
    plt.legend(['Green data','Black data','Red data'],loc='best')
    plt.xlabel("x data")
    plt.ylabel("y data")        
    plt.show()
```

Present output:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'legendHandles'
```

What is causing the error in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create the legend first.

`ax.get_legend()` only works after the legend was created.
Try `leg = ax.legend()` instead.

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.06-customizing-legends.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I tried this but got following error `leg.legendHandles[0].set_color('green')

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Mainland I took a closer look at your problem. If you simply put the `plt.legend` line before the `leg = ax.get_legend()` line, it seems to work just fine.